# start GUI interface from command line in snappy ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-core

How can i get into desktop /gui of snappy ubuntu from putty?

startx command is not working

or is there any way to do loke real vnc
m using raspberry pi2+snappy core

Answer (score 2):

Now there is https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/mir-snaps/ to package a single GUI application and bring it up on a snappy system.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Core is a minimal system and has such has no mechanism to display anything from the OS as there is no *GUI*

Answer (score 1):

Snappy Ubuntu is made for embedded and Internet-Of-Things devices. It has a CLI (command line) interface at best. It's supposed to be a very tiny bare-core Ubuntu,therefore no room for *giant* desktop environment (a.k.a. GUI).